# SnapDeal automation for gmail signin using Java with selenium webdriver with cucumber framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

In Snapdeal  when I hover to Sign In and click login  , it is opening signup dialog box and when I try to  login in  and click google Sign in, it is not finding the element.

```
@When("The user click login using google")

    public void the_user_click_login_using_google() {
    Set<String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = ids.iterator();
    String parentId = it.next();
    String childId = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(childId);
    l1=new LoginPojo();
    btnClick(l1.getGoogleuserlogin());
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='googleUserLogin')]")
    private WebElement googleuserlogin;
    public WebElement getGoogleuserlogin() {
    return googleuserlogin;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Element is in an `iframe`. I tried below code(in Python) and it worked.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/")
time.sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("googleUserLogin").click()
```